# Laravel + intervention image. Как загружать несколько картинок из формы?

Tags: php, laravel

Я пытаюсь создать контроллер, который будет получать несколько файлов из формы и загружать их через пакет Intervention Image. 
Собсна, вот контроллер:

```php
public function upload(Request $request){
    $files = $request->file('images');

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $image = Image::make($file)
            ->save($path);
    }
}
```

Форма:

```html
<form action="{{route('image.upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

И когда я нажимаю на заветную кнопку submit — сохраняется лишь один файл. Почему, и как исправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: пробовали глянуть в контроллере вывод dd($images); ?

Comment: @Yakoffka, конечно, пробовал. Если я отправляю несколько картинок, он и выводит мне несколько картинок. Но так или иначе, сохраняется только одна.

Comment: Попробуйте в цикле сохранять изображения с помощью create: Image::create($arrayfields);

Comment: @Yakoffka, хм, попробую.

Comment: Смотрите ответ и пример с англоязычного [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299407/laravel-5-5-multiple-images-upload). Проблема в том что имена файлов нужно задавать самому для сохранения.

Comment: @HELP Вы в цикле сохраняете файлы по одному пути, судя по коду.

Comment: @Pavel, спасибо! Проблема была именно в этом. Файлы "сливались", из-за чего сохранялся только один. Спасибо огромное.